# Android can not cast Context to Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I have a class which extends Activity.

```
      public class MyActivity extends Activity{

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                  setContentView(R.id,someactivitylayout);
                  new  Game(getApplicationContext());

       }
```

My Game class looks like

```
         public class Game{
             Game(final Context context){
                 cell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {

                       /* here i need to call runOnUIThread*/
                      }
              } 
         }
```

My code does not have any syntax errors, so it compiles fine.

In the place where i have to call runOnUIThread, i have tried

```
              Thread t = new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                        while (progressBar.getProgress() < 100) {
                               ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new unnable() {
                                                public void run() {

                                                }
                                            });
                                      }
                                };
                                t.start();
```

But when i try to cast context to Activity it gives an exception

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Why is it not possible to cast context to Activity??

I have tried many ways but did not find anyway to get Activity in my Game class.

Is there any way to do that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending ApplicationContext to the Game class. Just replace the `getApplicationContext()` with `this` to pass the Activity Context. It will work.

It should be `new Game(this)`

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.id,someactivitylayout);
        new Game(this);
    }
}
```